# How to install LAMP stack for Pop!_OS

Tags: webserver, pop-os

Is there a way to install the LAMP stack in a similar way to how the Windows WAMP installer works? I have been doing the installation manually. MySQL, PHP then APACHE then PHPMYADMIN is there not maybe a more succinct and robust way to install the complete LAMP stack without having to install every part of the stack one by one? Like how the WAMP install works on Windows.

Im on Pop_OS. What I mean by a windows like install is one where I dont have to install every part of the dtack one by one.

Answer (score 4):

On Pop!_OS, installing the `phpmyadmin` package will install the Apache web server and PHP for you. The only remaining step is to install the database server, since that is only “suggested” by the `phpmyadmin` package; to do this, install `default-mysql-server`.

You can do this in one step from the command line:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin default-mysql-server
```

Ubuntu also provides a “LAMP server” task; I haven’t checked in Pop!_OS, but unless Pop!_OS removes something related to this, you can install this set of packages with

```
sudo apt install 'lamp-server^'
```

This doesn’t include phpMyAdmin however, so you’d still need to install that explicitly.